# In a ring with identity, prove that (−1) · (−1)= 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm not sure how to start this problem with Rings, could someone perhaps lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Hello: please read the guidelines for [how to ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips to remember before you ask, and also at [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/29335) for question quality.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Prove that $(-1)(-1)+(-1)=0$.

Comment: I tried (-1) ((-1)(1)(1) + 1)